# Faster vector comparison in Julia

Tags: performance, comparison, julia, montecarlo

Im trying to construct and compare, the fastest possible way, two 01 random vectors of the same length using Julia, each vector with the same number of zeros and ones.

This is all for a MonteCarlo simulation of the following probabilistic question

> We have two independent urns, each one with n white balls and n black balls. Then we take a pair of balls, one of each urn, each time up to empty the urns. What is the probability that each pair have the same color?

What I did is the following:

```
using Random
# Auxiliar function that compare the parity, element by element, of two 
# random vectors of length 2n
function comp(n::Int64)
  sum((shuffle!(Vector(1:2*n)) .+ shuffle!(Vector(1:2*n))).%2)
end
```

The above generate two random permutations of the vector from 1 to 2n, add element by element, apply modulo 2 to each elemnt and after sum all the values of the remaining vector. Then Im using above the parity of each number to model it color: odd black and white even.

If the final sum is zero then the two random vectors had the same colors, element by element. A different result says that the two vectors doesnt had paired colors.

Then I setup the following function, that it is just the MonteCarlo simulation of the desired probability:

```
  # Here m is an optional argument that control the amount of random
  # experiments in the simulation
  function sim(n::Int64,m::Int64=24)
  # A counter for the valid cases
  x = 0
  for i in 1:2^m
    # A random pair of vectors is a valid case if they have the
    # the same parity element by element so
   if comp(n) == 0
    x += 1
   end
  end
  # The estimated value
   x/2^m
  end
```

Now I want to know if there is a faster way to compare such vectors. I tried the following alternative construction and comparison for the random vectors

```
shuffle!( repeat([0,1],n)) == shuffle!( repeat([0,1],n))
```

Then I changed accordingly the code to

```
comp(n)
```

With these changes the code runs slightly slower, what I tested with the function `@time`. Other changes that I did was changing the `for`statement for a `while`statement, but the computation time remain the same.

Because Im not programmer (indeed just yesterday I learn something of the Julia language, and installed the Juno front-end) then probably will be a faster way to make the same computations. Some tip will be appreciated because the effectiveness of a MonteCarlo simulation depends on the number of random experiments, so the faster the computation the larger values we can test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key cost in this problem is `shuffle!` therefore in order to maximize the simulation speed you can use (I add it as an answer as it is too long for a comment):

```
function test(n,m)
  ref = [isodd(i) for i in 1:2n]
  sum(all(view(shuffle!(ref), 1:n)) for i in 1:m) / m
end
```

What are the differences from the code proposed in the other answer:

1. You do not have to `shuffle!` both vectors; it is enough to `shuffle!` one of them, as the result of the comparison is invariant to any identical permutation of both vectors after independently shuffling them; therefore we can assume that one vector is after random permutation reshuffled to be ordered so that it has `trues` in the first `n` entries and `falses` in the last `n` entries
2. I do `shuffle!` in-place (i.e. `ref` vector is allocated only once)
3. I use `all` function on the fist half of the vector; this way the check is stopped as I hit first `false`; if I hit all `true` in the first `n` entries I do not have to check the last `n` entries as I know they are all `false` so I do not have to check them

Comment: about shuffling just one: I already tested it before to post my code, however letting one vector fixed and shuffling the other gives a very different value of the estimated probability, what is very strange. Anyway I will test it again, maybe I did something wrong the first time

Comment: I have checked this and it gives the same probability for me. Compare results for my code and for One Lyner code to see that they are the same for large `m` and the same `n`.

Comment: I have just checked it against your code and it gives also the same results.

Comment: yes, I see. I surely written something wrong when I tested yesterday. Thank you very much.

Comment: One more thing regarding the solution. I use `view` to avoid allocation the first part of the `ref` vector which would happen if I have written `shuffle!(ref)[1:n]`.

Answer (score 2):

To get something cleaner, you could generate directly vectors of 0/1 values, and then just let Julia check for vector equality, e.g.

```
function rndvec(n::Int64)
 shuffle!(vcat(zeros(Bool,n),ones(Bool,n)))
end

function sim0(n::Int64, m::Int64=24)
  sum(rndvec(n) == rndvec(n) for i in 1:2^m) / 2^m
end
```

Avoiding allocation makes the code faster, as explained by Bogumił Kamiński (and letting Julia make the comparison is faster than his code).

```
function sim1(n::Int64, m::Int64=24)
  vref = vcat(zeros(Bool,n),ones(Bool,n))
  vshuffled = vref[:]
  sum(shuffle!(vshuffled) == vref for i in 1:2^m) / 2^m
end
```

To go even faster use lazy evaluation and fast exit: if the first element is different, you don't even need to generate the rest of the vectors.
This would make the code much trickier though.

I find it's a bit not in the spirit of the question, but you could also do some more math.
There is `binomial(2*n, n)` possible vectors generated and you could therefore just compute

```
function sim2(n::Int64, m::Int64=24)
   nvec = binomial(2*n, n)
   sum(rand(1:nvec) == 1 for i in 1:2^m) / 2^m
end
```

Here are some timings I obtain:

```
@time show(("sim0", sim0(6, 21)))
@time show(("sim1", sim1(6, 21)))
@time show(("sim2", sim2(6, 21)))
@time test(("test", test(6, 2^21)))

("sim0", 0.0010724067687988281)  4.112159 seconds (12.68 M allocations: 1.131 GiB, 11.47% gc time)
("sim1", 0.0010781288146972656)  0.916075 seconds (19.87 k allocations: 1.092 MiB)
("sim2", 0.0010628700256347656)  0.249432 seconds (23.12 k allocations: 1.258 MiB)
("test", 0.0010166168212890625)  1.180781 seconds (2.14 M allocations: 98.634 MiB, 2.22% gc time)
```

Comment: Im seeing now the edition of your answer. Thank you very much again, I will study carefully your tips and also about how Julia language works to improve efficiency next time.